# How to remove head values in a pandas variable

Tags: python, pandas

I want to exclude head values from a pandas variable,
This variable looks like...

```
AJ [ 2 ]       53
CN [ 2 ]       65
SE [ 2 ]       65
LAUP [ 2 ]     63
NT [ 2 ]       53
SEADF [ 2 ]    65
```

and I want to make it like this :

```
marks = [53, 65, 65, 63, 53, 65]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Solution,
Convert it into np.array (Numpy Array)

```
marks = np.array(SutudentData) #StudentData ---> variable
```